# Solución a error de instalación de paquete Node JS. ENOTFOUND

Tags: nodejs, npm

Al querer instalar un paquete a través de npm:

```
npm install -g javascripting
```

me sale este error:
C:\Users\ventas\javascripting>npm install -g javascripting
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/javascripting failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy proxy:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ventas\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-06-16T10_27_05_328Z-debug.log

Si me pudieran indicar si hay soluciòn a dicho error.

Comment: tienes un problema para hacer la petición, estás detrás de un proxy?

Comment: ¿Que pasa si haces `ping https://registry.npmjs.org/javascripting`? El error indica que no encuentra el recurso de red. Verifica que puedes hacer peticiones a `npmjs.org`

Comment: C:\Users\ventas>ping https://registry.npmjs.org/javascripting
La solicitud de ping no pudo encontrar el host https://registry.npmjs.org/javascripting. Compruebe el nombre y
vuelva a intentarlo.

Comment: No incluyas el path completo, solo el host, así: `ping registry.npmjs.org`

Comment: Hice como me dijiste y saliò esto:Haciendo ping a registry.npmjs.org [104.16.16.35] con 32 bytes de datos:
Respuesta desde 104.16.16.35: bytes=32 tiempo=62ms TTL=56
Respuesta desde 104.16.16.35: bytes=32 tiempo=53ms TTL=56
Respuesta desde 104.16.16.35: bytes=32 tiempo=16ms TTL=56
Respuesta desde 104.16.16.35: bytes=32 tiempo=162ms TTL=56

Estadísticas de ping para 104.16.16.35:
    Paquetes: enviados = 4, recibidos = 4, perdidos = 0
    (0% perdidos),
Tiempos aproximados de ida y vuelta en milisegundos:
    Mínimo = 16ms, Máximo = 162ms, Media = 73ms

Comment: Luego, intenté instalar de nuevo un paquete, y sae error de nuevo: C:\Users\ventas>npm install -g javascripting
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/javascripting failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 93.184.216.34:8080
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de `npm` tienes? Por favor ejecuta lo siguiente: `npm config get registry`, luego ejecuta: `npm config get http-proxy` y por último `npm get config https-proxy`, comenta los resultados. Hay un problema en la configuración de `npm` y es lo que estoy tratando de aclarar. Saludos

Comment: Tengo de npm la versión 6.9.0. Voy a seguir los pasos que me dices y te aviso.

Comment: Esto es lo que obtengo al seguir tus pasos: C:\Users\ventas>npm config get registry
https://registry.npmjs.org/

C:\Users\ventas>npm config get http-proxy
undefined

C:\Users\ventas>npm get config https-proxy
undefined

Comment: pudiste resolver? Yo tengo el mismo problema.

Comment: probablemente necesites ejecutar el comando con privilegios administrativo

Comment: @JackNavaRow disculpa me puedes explica cómo hacerlo?